# Error while creating default partition postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I have created tables with list partitions. All partition tables got created but I face with an error while creating DEFAULT partition.

Below is the error I faced. I'm using Postgres 10.4.

```
create table test (id int, val int) partition by list(val); --worked fine

create table test_1 partition of test for values in (1); --worked fine

create table test_def partition of test DEFAULT; --throws error
```

For the last statement I get the below error.

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "DEFAULT"

Please help.

Comment: Upgrade from Postgres 10 to 12.

Comment: @klin: you meant **11** or 12

Comment: 11?! It was so long ago...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default partitions are not supported until PostgreSQL 11.

See [version 11 release notes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/release-11.html) for more information

Disclosure: I am an EnterpriseDB (EDB) employee.